# Postman - reuse the token

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

how I can reuse the token from one collection to another in postman?  So i can run in parallel multiple folders

I tried storing and reusing but haven't succeeded
`pm.environment.set("token", responseBody.access_token);`

Answer (score 2):

you can use it through `Environment` option, PFA screenshot for reference

[image]

- click on highlighted icon and then add any varibale name(i.e. token).
- then go to `Tests` under your token api and add below script under `Tests`. (below script will take token response from api and set it to the environment varibale, change response object as per your response data.)

```
const response = pm.response.json(); 
pm.environment.set("token",`Bearer ${response.Token}`);
```

- now start using `{{token}}` wherever required.

> Note: remember to select the environment from right top corner which you created, while consuming the varibales

***we can use this across all collections***

***Add On:*** if you want you can even set variables as Global, Collection, Environment as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Storing the token as global variable should do:

```
pm.globals.set("token", responseBody.access_token);
```

Postman has different variable scopes: Global, Collection, Environment, Data and Local:

> Global variables enable you to access data between collections, requests, test scripts, and environments.

You can read more about it here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes